# $\sum_{p,q \text{ primes }  p \le q}  1/(pq\log(pq))$

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series

The sum $$ \sum\limits_{p,q \text{ primes }  p \le q}  \frac{1}{pq\log(pq)}$$

is related to a conjecture of Erdős about primitive sequences.

It converges because the sequence is primitive. If my calculations are correct a lower bound is $1.062$.

> Is it known to what is equal the sum?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no, and I doubt very much it is a decent number. In general, if you cannot immediately express the sum over primes in terms of the $\zeta$-function using Euler's formula, it is hopeless because the explicit summation of whatever is not encoded in Euler requires knowledge of *individual* primes and that is well beyond the current state of art. Actually, even if you can express things in terms of $\zeta$, it is rather questionable whether it can be called "an explicit formula" because we don't know much about the values of $\zeta$ except at the even integers.

Comment: Thank you fedja, will accept this as answer. What do you mean by "decent number"? I suppose unconditional upper bound follows from the primitive sequence.

Comment: Perhaps of interest:  You can rewrite your sum as $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_{1}^{\infty}P(s)^{2}ds+\int_{1}^{\infty}P(2s)ds\right)$$ where $P(s)=\sum_{p} p^{-s}$ is the prime zeta function.

Comment: Thank you Eric. Can you give a lower bound?